# What is a word that means "usually overlooked yet critical to results"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm describing topics for exam preparation. *"The seldom reviewed but always encountered"* topics on the exam."

Comment: *unappreciated* or *under-appreciated* or *undervalued* or *underestimated*

Answer (score 3):

If you really want a "single word", you could go for something like ***oft-ignored, oft-forgotten, oft-overlooked***, but I seriously doubt there's anything (based on that construction or not) that would disambiguate between things *students* fail to revise for, as opposed to things the *teachers* fail to review. Or indeed, anything that significantly implies such things are *always* encountered after that lack of preparation.

Comment: I'd apply FF's succinct "oft-overlooked" and tack on "yet critical" to satisfy the 2nd part of your request, @Terrie.  So I'd say "oft-overlooked, yet critical".

Comment: @Kristina: My first thought was that these ***oft-xxxxx*** forms are getting to be somewhat "dated", but checking [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oft-ignored%2Coft-forgotten%2Coft-overlooked&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coft%20-%20ignored%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coft%20-%20forgotten%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coft%20-%20overlooked%3B%2Cc0) I find they've all become much more common in recent decades. I also note that ***oft-overlooked*** is now more common than ***oft-forgotten***, which always used to be the "group leader".

Comment: And in the US you would probably use "often" in place of "oft".

Comment: :GEdgar: That preference is [just the same in BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oft-ignored%2Coft-forgotten%2Coft-overlooked%2Coften+ignored%2Coften+forgotten%2Coften+overlooked&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coft%20-%20ignored%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coft%20-%20forgotten%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coft%20-%20overlooked%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coften%20ignored%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coften%20forgotten%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coften%20overlooked%3B%2Cc0). But per previous link, ***oft-*** is on the *increase* both sides of the pond, not falling into disuse.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening discussion on my first post to SE! @FF@Kristina: The familiar but forgotten **oft-XXX** with the addition of **yet critical** didn't get me down to one word, yet in the end, that's what I used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a word that means exactly what you've described, and if there were it probably wouldn't be universally understood. But **"[elementary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elementary)"** seems fairly close, as it implies that something elementary is: 1) important and fundamental to know, and 2) so basic that it doesn't warrant much attention by the professor.